# Is there a tool that makes it possible to validate Jenkinsfiles online?

Tags: jenkins-blueocean

At the moment I am editing a Jenkinsfile and then let it run unless Jenkins reports a issue. This approach costs a lot of time. I prefer to validate the syntax before committing the Jenkinsfile. Is there a tool that solves this issue?

In [gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#validate-the-gitlab-ci-yml) there is a URI, i.e. `/ci/lint` that makes it possible to submit a gitlab file, click on the check button and then the UI will indicate whether the syntax is correct or not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is some documentation on the Jenkins pipeline linter and its commands. Do you need to validate **before** a commit? If not, it would be really trivial to run the linting command prior to your pipeline running, and simply fail if it does not pass.

From [Command-line Pipeline Linter](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/development/#linter):

> Jenkins can validate, or "[lint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software))", a Declarative Pipeline from the
>   command line before actually running it. This can be done using a
>   Jenkins CLI command or by making an HTTP POST request with appropriate
>   parameters. We recommended using the [SSH interface](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/#ssh) to run the
>   linter. See the [Jenkins CLI documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/) for details on how to
>   properly configure Jenkins for secure command-line access.
>
> *Linting via the CLI with SSH*
>
> ```
> # ssh (Jenkins CLI)
> # JENKINS_SSHD_PORT=[sshd port on master]
> # JENKINS_HOSTNAME=[Jenkins master hostname]
> ssh -p $JENKINS_SSHD_PORT $JENKINS_HOSTNAME declarative-linter < Jenkinsfile
> ```
>
> *Linting via HTTP POST using `curl`*
>
> ```
> # curl (REST API)
> # Assuming "anonymous read access" has been enabled on your Jenkins instance.
> # JENKINS_URL=[root URL of Jenkins master]
> # JENKINS_CRUMB is needed if your Jenkins master has CRSF protection enabled as it should
> JENKINS_CRUMB=`curl "$JENKINS_URL/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,\":\",//crumb)"`
> curl -X POST -H $JENKINS_CRUMB -F "jenkinsfile=<Jenkinsfile" $JENKINS_URL/pipeline-model-converter/validate
> ```
>
> **Examples**
>
> Below are two examples of the Pipeline Linter in action. This first
>   example shows the output of the linter when it is passed an invalid
>   `Jenkinsfile`, one that is missing part of the `agent` declaration.
>
> *Jenkinsfile*
>
> ```
> pipeline {
>   agent
>   stages {
>     stage ('Initialize') {
>       steps {
>         echo 'Placeholder.'
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> *Linter output for invalid Jenkinsfile*
>
> ```
> # pass a Jenkinsfile that does not contain an "agent" section
> ssh -p 8675 localhost declarative-linter < ./Jenkinsfile
> Errors encountered validating Jenkinsfile:
> WorkflowScript: 2: Not a valid section definition: "agent". Some extra configuration is required. @ line 2, column 3.
>      agent
>      ^
>
> WorkflowScript: 1: Missing required section "agent" @ line 1, column 1.
>    pipeline &#125;
>    ^
> ```
>
> In this second example, the `Jenkinsfile` has been updated to include
>   the missing `any` on `agent`. The linter now reports that the Pipeline
>   is valid.
>
> *Jenkinsfile*
>
> ```
> pipeline {
>   agent any
>   stages {
>     stage ('Initialize') {
>       steps {
>         echo 'Placeholder.'
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> *Linter output for valid Jenkinsfile*
>
> ```
> ssh -p 8675 localhost declarative-linter < ./Jenkinsfile
> Jenkinsfile successfully validated.
> ```

Comment: Could you explain how to use the client locally? `java -jar jenkins-cli.jar [-s JENKINS_URL] [global options...] command [command options...] [arguments...]`

Comment: https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/2164/210

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer. Is there an online tool as well? It would be great if one could navigate to a UI, post a jenkinsfile and check whether there are syntax issues. I have updated the question.

Comment: @030 I doubt that there is an online linter tool, but it sounds like a fun project to take on :) To use the linter locally, you need to login to your Jenkins server with your credentials, then "ask" Jenkins to lint your jenkinsfile. http://www.pierre-beitz.eu/2017/01/17/Writing-a-Jenkinsfile-Tips-and-Tricks.html

Comment: Could you add some snippets from that link to this answer. If the link is deprecated, the information would be gone.

Comment: Good point. Added.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for complex pipelines which use shared library. In particular, it strictly requires your Jenkinsfile to have `pipeline` block which we have encapsulated in some shared library call...