# Why does the jenkins-cli.jar linting functionality not work?

Tags: jenkins, linting

The jenkins-cli.jar has been downloaded.

It is able to run.

When one tries to check the syntax of a jenkinsfile by running `java -jar ~/Desktop/jenkins-cli.jar -s https://<jenkins_url> -noCertificateCheck declarative-linter < Jenkinsfile` it results in:

```
Sep 27, 2017 10:46:18 AM hudson.cli.CLI _main
INFO: Skipping HTTPS certificate checks altogether. Note that this is not secure at all.
Sep 27, 2017 10:46:34 AM hudson.cli.CLI$5 run
WARNING: null
java.io.IOException: Stream is closed
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.checkError(HttpURLConnection.java:3512)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.write(HttpURLConnection.java:3486)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeInt(DataOutputStream.java:197)
        at hudson.cli.PlainCLIProtocol$EitherSide.send(PlainCLIProtocol.java:188)
        at hudson.cli.PlainCLIProtocol$EitherSide.send(PlainCLIProtocol.java:195)
        at hudson.cli.PlainCLIProtocol$EitherSide$1.write(PlainCLIProtocol.java:215)
        at hudson.cli.CLI$5.run(CLI.java:699)
```

@Tensibai asked whether there is an authentication issue. Authentication was done, but it is unclear whether it was succesfull or not:

```
$ java -jar ~/Desktop/jenkins-cli.jar -noCertificateCheck -s https://<jenkins url> login --username <username> --password <password>
Sep 27, 2017 10:57:17 AM hudson.cli.CLI _main
INFO: Skipping HTTPS certificate checks altogether. Note that this is not secure at all.
```

Comment: Seems your jenkins url refuse the connexion, doesn't it need an authentication ?

Comment: @Tensibai question has been updated

Comment: Maybe: `java -jar ~/Desktop/jenkins-cli.jar -s https://<jenkins_url> -noCertificateCheck --username <username> --password <password> declarative-linter < Jenkinsfile` ? there's a bunch of blur about auth with different versions on [jenkins site](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI)

Comment: it returned the same null pointer and stack trace

Comment: Version of the cli ? format of the url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrading Jenkins the issue was solved. It turned out that the issue was version related.